# Please be sure to call `initializeAuth` or `getAuth` before starting any other Firebase SDK. [Firebase Auth on NextJS App]

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my NextJS App on Vercel. But I'm getting this error.

Also, my project runs smoothly in development mode, but why am I getting such an error while deploying?

***Firebase.ts File***

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  getAuth,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { handlerSetUser } from "./utils";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user: any) => {
  if (user) {
    handlerSetUser(user);
  } else {
    handlerSetUser(false);
  }
});

export const login = async (email: any, password: any) => {
  try {
    const result = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    return result;
  } catch (error: any) {
    alert(error.message);
  }
};

export const logout = async () => {
  try {
    await signOut(auth);
  } catch (error: any) {
    alert(error.message);
  }
};
```

***Vercel Deployment Error***

```
_errorFactory: ErrorFactory {
    service: 'auth',
    serviceName: 'Firebase',
    errors: {
      'dependent-sdk-initialized-before-auth': 'Another Firebase SDK was initialized and is trying to use Auth before Auth is initialized. Please be sure to call `initializeAuth` or `getAuth` before starting any other Firebase SDK.'
    }
  },
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am running into the same problem locally.

Comment: @AustinS Hi, I was getting this error during deployment. There was another error during NextJS SSR, and when I removed that error, this problem was solved.